# Iridescence shader is not iridescent, only banded

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I got this from a tutorial I found on YouTube. It's supposed to create an iridescent surface, but creates only bands of green and black, and that only after I changed the value in the Multiply node to 0.5. I have no idea what to change, or if this setup is fundamentally flawed.

[image: The shader nodes]

Comment: To be honest, quite often beginners are asking about things they are simply missing in tutorials because it can be tricky if you don't have the experience what details you have to pay attention to. So I'm not going to rebuild this shader setup on my own just to get the same result as you. Maybe it would help if you put a link to the tutorial in the question so we could see for ourselves where you might have been wrong. But sometimes it could also be a flaw in the tutorial so without the video it's hard to tell what is going on. From what I see there it doesn't make any sense for iridescence.

Comment: The tutorial is here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/iI012TE8fjU)

Comment: I found a much better tutorial.

Comment: Okay, good you found a better tutorial. I found what is wrong with your setup. The _Color Mix_ node is set to the default _Mix_, but in the tutorial he switches it to _Multiply_.